# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished getting started with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am absolutely new to Ruby on Rails and I'm following a book that's written as a tutorial, but it is a bit outdated.

When I run the server and browse `localhost:3000` something is not working right, I get the following error: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

MySQL is installed in my computer, the databases are created and all of this works in other example applications I have been giving a look to.

This is the `databases.yml` file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: emporium_development
  username: emporium
  password: hacked

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: emporium_test
  username: emporium
  password: hacked
```

I made sure the mysql2 gem is installed like this: `gem install mysql2`

Shed some light on me please.

Comment: have you run rake db:migrate?

Comment: ummm I don't know what that is. But I just managed to run it successfully it after some problems (changed `sqlite3` for `mysql2` in the `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install` and installed a required adapter) and it seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? Can you add the error stacktrace in your question.

Comment: maybe you should start again at zero and use another tutorial like http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

First setup your gems by running

```
Bundle install
```

Then your database needs to be created:

```
rake db:create
```

If you have some pending migrations (and if you don't this can still be run, it just won't do anything):

```
rake db:migrate
```

This should setup a database that works, provided you gave the correct password.

Note that if you already have a database that you want to get rid of, you can run

```
rake db:drop
```

and then try to create the database again.

Does any of this solve your problem ?